# SonarCloud Authorization Error during Build

Tags: java, maven, sonarcloud

I know there exist similar topics but they didn't solve my problem.
As suggested in the corresponding posts I followed the steps in:

https://about.sonarcloud.io/get-started/

(I did this several times with different tokens to make sure I didn't make a copy-paste mistake with the token or the organization name.)

More precise, in my project-directory I used:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent package sonar:sonar \
    -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io \
    -Dsonar.organization=your_organization_key \
    -Dsonar.login=abcdef0123456789
```

with my own organization-key and the previously created token as login.

And I still get this mistake (rest of the build works perfectly fine):

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project list: You're only authorized to execute a local (preview) SonarQube analysis without pushing the results to the SonarQube server. Please contact your SonarQube administrator. -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project list: You're only authorized to execute a local (preview) SonarQube analysis without pushing the results to the SonarQube server. Please contact your SonarQube administrator.
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: You're only authorized to execute a local (preview) SonarQube analysis without pushing the results to the SonarQube server. Please contact your SonarQube administrator.
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:80)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:139)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>       ... 20 more

Any further ideas? Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot to answer my own question, so here it is.

When writing the question (don't know if this still is the case) it turned out that the artifact name (I think it was artifact) had to be *globally unique for Sonarcloud* as it seemed (maybe in context with other identifying information). So changing that did the trick for me (uniqueness as not given as several people in the same class encountered this problem; kudos to my tutor who finally found out).